# Defining relationships with Access SQL in conjunction with IN statement

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am trying to query data from a number of tables using MS Access and SQL. The query involves a large number of criteria. For example here is the code I am currently using:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tblA]
IN "G:\path\data.mdb"
WHERE ((([tblA].[var1])="435")) 
      OR ((([tblA].[var1])="3")) 
      OR ((([tblA].[var1])="4")) 
      OR ((([tblA].[var1])="634")) 
      OR ((([tblA].[var1])="234")) 
      OR ((([tblA].[var1])="234"));
```

The number of criteria can be as high as 50, and they will be different each time someone uses this code. The problem is worse since this is part of a longer code that requires the entry of these criteria multiple times.

Instead of having users enter in the criteria, I wanted to create an excel file with these constraints as a primary key, then set var1 in tblA as a foreign key and reference the primary key in the excel table. That way I could run:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tblA]
IN "G:\path\data.mdb"
```

and I would only get the data that meets all the above criteria. Does anyone know how to create these relationships when you are connecting to an outside table using an IN statement? Can `ALTER TABLE` be used? If so, where in the code?

Comment: what is the problem you have to implement this solution as the best solution? Describe the problem you tried to solve

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of that is as simple as you're requesting here.  You can write your initial query as [tblA].[var1] in (435,3,4,84394).  It can also work as where var1 in (select idlist from othertable).  There are methods of using excel (under data connections) to upload a list into access and use that as your criteria and have results appear in excel.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is querying data from multiple databases subject to a large number of criteria, where the criteria varies each time the code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be difficult (or impossible) to create an actual Relationship between a table `IN` another database and a spreadsheet in yet another file, but for your specific purposes it really isn't necessary. If your criteria were in an Excel sheet like this ...

[image: Excel.png]

... then you could just use a `WHERE var1 IN (SELECT ...)` clause like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [tblA]
IN "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\data.mdb"
WHERE 
    var1 IN (
        SELECT CStr(var1)
        FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\criteria.xls].[Sheet1$]
    )
```